# Make Jersey RESTful server compliant with Ember Data and JSON API

Tags: rest, ember.js, jersey, ember-data, json-api

I currently run a server that serves data like this:

**single entity**

```
{"id":"11","name":"hello",....}
```

**list of entities**

```
[{single entity format},{},...]
```

However, Ember Data expects data to follow the [JSON API spec](http://jsonapi.org/), in the format of

```
{"entity":{"id":"11","name":"hello",....}} OR {"entities":[{},{},{}...]}
```

or else it will return error:

```
Your server returned a hash with the key 0 but you have no mapping for it
```

I currently have a `responseFactory` which will build the response as a map with key being the ember model ("users"/"user") the entity/list and value being the list/entity itself

**Is there a better/cleaner way?**

Answer (score 3):

Please check this project on github: https://github.com/brunorg/ember-java

What you need is the `@JsonRootName` Jackson annotation. I believe that this is the cleaner way.

Comment: I'm also trying to configure Jackson correctly to use with ember. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659835/how-to-deserialize-field-from-object-based-on-annotation-using-jackson

Answer (score 1):

In your case try to use class like so :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

@JsonRootName("entity")
public class Entity {
   @JsonProperty
   public ArrayList<HashMap> entity = new ArrayList<HashMap>(); 

   public Entity() {    }

   public User(HashMap<String,Object> fields) {
      entity.add(fields);
   }
}
```

and produce so :

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Entity producePost(Object object) {
    HashMap<String, Object> f = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    f.put("id", "11");
    f.put("name", "hello...");
    return new Entity(f);
}
```

it allow produce in format that Ember can accept
like this

```
 {
  "entity" : [ {
    "id" : "11",
    "name" : "hello...."
  } ]
}
```