# How to (De)serialize field from object based on annotation using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, ember.js, jackson, ember-data

I need to configure Jackson in a specific way which I'll describe below.

## Requirements

1. Annotated fields are serialized with only their id:

   - If the field is a normal object, serialize its `id`
   - If the field is a collection of objects, serialize an array of `id`
2. Annotated fields get their property names serialized differently:

   - If the field is a normal object, add `"_id"` suffix to property name
   - If the field is a collection of objects, add `"_ids"` suffix to property name
3. For the annotation I was thinking something like a custom `@JsonId`, ideally with an optional value to override the name just like `@JsonProperty` does
4. The id property should be defined by the user, either using:

   - The already existing Jackson's `@JsonIdentityInfo`
   - Or by creating another class or field annotation
   - Or by deciding which annotation to inspect for `id` property discoverability (useful for JPA scenarios, for example)
5. Objects should be serialized with a wrapped root value
6. Camel case naming should be converted to lower case with underscores
7. All of this should be deserializable (by constructing an instance with just the id setted)

## An example

Considering these POJO's:

```
//Inform Jackson which property is the id
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id"
)
public abstract class BaseResource{
    protected Long id;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Resource extends BaseResource{
    private String name;
    @JsonId
    private SubResource subResource;
    @JsonId
    private List<SubResource> subResources;

    //getters and setters
}

public class SubResource extends BaseResource{
    private String value;

    //getters and setters
}
```

A possible serialization of a `Resource` instance could be:

```
{
    "resource":{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "bla",
        "sub_resource_id": 2,
        "sub_resource_ids": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
}
```

## So far...

- Requirement **#5** can be accomplished by configuring `ObjectMapper` in the following way:

  ```
  objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
  objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
  ```

  And then using `@JsonRootName("example_root_name_here")` in my POJO's.
- Requirement **#6** can be accomplished by configuring `ObjectMapper` in the following way:

  ```
  objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
      PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
  ```

As you can see there are still lots of requirements to fulfill. For those wondering why I need such a configuration, it's because I'm developing a REST webservice for [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) (more specifically Ember Data).
You would appreciate very much if you could help with any of the requirements.

Thanks!

Comment: how was the experience? I'm exactly facing this requirements now. If you could provide your configuration decisions it would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you looked into creating your own `AnnotationIntrospector`?

Comment: I also have to interact with ember data. I've seen newer Jackson versions provide features to ease this. What was your solution?  p.s. I'm looking over the approved answer for insight.

Comment: @ieugen Right now I would go the JSONApi route and try katharsis: http://www.katharsis.io/

Ember Data supports JSONApi standard out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @miguelcobain . I was looking at  khatarsis . I'm using Vertx.io and hopefully I'll be able to integrate them ok. Just to clarify: can you confirm ember data integrates out-of-the-box-ish with khatarsis?

Comment: @ieugen There maybe some open issues on that. https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-core/issues/32

But they definitely should be compatible as they both should implement the smae spec. I can't confirm as I'm not really using Katharsis. I'm stuck with Jackson with my ugly hacks to make it conform the previous Ember Data. If you're starting now, JSONAPI is definitely the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most (all?) of your requirements can be accomplished through the use of a contextual serializer.  Taking one answer from [ContextualDeserializer for mapping JSON to different types of maps with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704992/contextualdeserializer-for-mapping-json-to-different-types-of-maps-with-jackson) and Jackson's wiki (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureContextualHandlers) I was able to come up with the following.

You need to start with the @JsonId annotation, which is the key indicating a property needs to only use the Id property.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation // important so that it will get included!
public @interface JsonId {
}
```

Next is the actual ContextualSerializer, which does the heavy lifting.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ContextualJsonIdSerializer
    extends JsonSerializer<BaseResource>
    implements ContextualSerializer/*<BaseResource>*/
{
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private boolean useJsonId;

    public ContextualJsonIdSerializer(ObjectMapper mapper) { this(mapper, false); }
    public ContextualJsonIdSerializer(ObjectMapper mapper, boolean useJsonId) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.useJsonId = useJsonId;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(BaseResource br, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
    {
        if ( useJsonId ) {
            jgen.writeString(br.getId().toString());
        } else {
            mapper.writeValue(jgen, br);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<BaseResource> createContextual(SerializerProvider config, BeanProperty property)
            throws JsonMappingException
    {
        // First find annotation used for getter or field:
        System.out.println("Finding annotations for "+property);

        if ( null == property ) {
            return new ContextualJsonIdSerializer(mapper, false);
        }

        JsonId ann = property.getAnnotation(JsonId.class);
        if (ann == null) { // but if missing, default one from class
            ann = property.getContextAnnotation(JsonId.class);
        }
        if (ann == null ) {//|| ann.length() == 0) {
            return this;//new ContextualJsonIdSerializer(false);
        }
        return new ContextualJsonIdSerializer(mapper, true);
    }
}
```

This class looks at `BaseResource` properties and inspects them to see if the `@JsonId` annotation is present.  If it is then only the Id property is used, otherwise a passed in `ObjectMapper` is used to serialize the value.  This is important because if you try to use the mapper that is (basically) in the context of the `ContextualSerializer` then you will get a stack overflow since it will eventually call these methods over and over.

You're resource should look something like the following.  I used the `@JsonProperty` annotation instead of wrapping the functionality in the `ContextualSerializer` because it seemed silly to reinvent the wheel.

```
import java.util.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class Resource extends BaseResource{
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("sub_resource_id")
    @JsonId
    private SubResource subResource;

    @JsonProperty("sub_resource_ids")
    @JsonId
    private List<SubResource> subResources;

    //getters and setters
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public SubResource getSubResource() {return subResource;}
    public void setSubResource(SubResource subResource) {this.subResource = subResource;}

    public List<SubResource> getSubResources() {return subResources;}
    public void setSubResources(List<SubResource> subResources) {this.subResources = subResources;}
}
```

Finally the method that performs the serialization just creates an additional `ObjectMapper` and  registers a module in the original `ObjectMapper`.

```
// Create the original ObjectMapper
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);

// Create a clone of the original ObjectMapper
ObjectMapper objectMapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper2.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
objectMapper2.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
objectMapper2.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);

// Create a module that references the Contextual Serializer
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("JsonId", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
// All references to SubResource should be run through this serializer
module.addSerializer(SubResource.class, new ContextualJsonIdSerializer(objectMapper2));
objectMapper.registerModule(module);

// Now just use the original objectMapper to serialize
```